# Correct way to create Python egg for CherryPy webapp

Tags: python, wsgi, cherrypy, easy-install, egg

I've created a small CherryPy webapp and now want to create a Python egg for easy installation. The folder structure of my app is as follows:

```
|--MyApp
|    |--wsgi.py
|    |--server_config.cfg
|    |--setup.py
|    |--MyApp/
|    |    |--__init.py__
|    |    |--myapp.py
|    |--Templates
|    |    |--index.html
|    |    |--response.html
```

To run standalone, I just run `python wsgi.py` which is the main entry point for the webapp:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    cherrypy.config.update({
        'server.socket_host': socket_host,
        'server.socket_port': int(port),
    })

    # Run the application using CherryPy's HTTP Web Server
    cherrypy.quickstart(myapp(), '/', conf)
```

In my setup.py, I have the following set as the entry point:

```
setup(
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'myapp=wsgi:main',
        ],
    },
 )
```

The setup compiles fine into the egg and running easy_install myapp installs fine along with all the dependancies. However when I then go to run myapp, I get a Python stack trace with the last line being: `ImportError: No module named wsgi`

Any thoughts? Am I not setting the entry point correctly in setup.py? Thanks!

Comment: Look at ``package_data`` argument for ``setup()``.

Comment: Wouldn't `packages = find_packages()` get everything I need?

Comment: The ``find_packages()`` function from ``setuptools`` may help to a degree, but it will only pick up Python code files which fit what it is looking for. It will not pick up non Python code files like template files. Overall am not even sure why you are trying to install it as an egg in the first place as you wouldn't need to do that to use it with a WSGi server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [uWSGI says: "ImportError: No module named wsgi"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864044/uwsgi-says-importerror-no-module-named-wsgi)